# Pandas в Colab. Не полностью считывается содержимое ячейки

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

Есть csv таблица, в ней в третьей колонке находятся ссылки в формате https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hNgBiPNNYxmYa4uOu3LvYWEEWn9cvjtZMnyNzLNwyw/edit?usp=sharing

На:

```py
a = input("введите язык в формате: якутский  ")
k = df[df["Языки"] == a]
```

выдается:

```
Языки Сумма индексов финальная  \
3  адыгейский                       35   

                                            описание  
3  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ARfFRAjWA2...
```

Как видно, ссылка выдается не полностью. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Так это вопрос отображения. Либо настройками `pandas` снимаете ограничение на размер показываемых данных. Либо берёте значение из конкретной ячейки датафрейма и печатаете его через `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это вопрос отображения. Максимальный показываемый размер для колонки регулируется соответствующей опцией, например, можно полностью отключить ограничение:

```py
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None
```